# How to get notifications for messages for a user

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have a task to display count of messages for the logged-in user and also to display/notify the messages on for the user.

so far what I have done is not displaying the messages. any help will be appreciated.

```
  public class NotificationsController : Controller
    {
        readonly INotificationService ins = null;
        List<Message> oMessages = new();
        readonly UserManager<User> usm;
        
        public NotificationsController(INotificationService  notificationService, UserManager<User>userManager )
        {
            ins = notificationService;
            usm = userManager;
           
        }

        public IActionResult AllNotifications()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetNotifications(bool bIsGetOnlyRead=false)
        {
            
            string ReceiverId = "SuperAdmin";
            oMessages = new List<Message>();
            oMessages = ins.GetNotifications(ReceiverId, bIsGetOnlyRead);  
            
            return Json(oMessages);
        }
    }
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("$noti_Container").ikrNotificationSetup();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Notifications/GetNotifications",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var notifications = data;
            $("#noti_Container").ikrNotificationCount({
                NotificationList: notifications,
                NotiFromPropName: "Sender",
                ListTitlePropName: "Subject",
                ListBodyPropName: "Body",
                ControllerName: "Notifications",
                ActionName: "AllNotifications"
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) { }
    });

})
```

```
   <li class="nav-item"><div id="noti_Container"></div></li>
```

I want something like this image
[image: sample output]

Comment: The selector `$("$noti_Container")` seems incorrect. It should be `$("#noti_Container")`.add the code for the error handling to get more detail:  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error("Error fetching notifications:", error);
and check console for error logs if is there any.

Comment: Thank you.  I have changed it now and the list is showing.  However, the presentation is my challenge now.  How can i have control over the display.  the display is showing all the items instead of a few of them

Comment: could you try adding the `success: function (data) {
            var notifications = data;
            var limitedNotifications = notifications.slice(0, 5);` in your code

Comment: Sorry I cant possibly teach you how to use web sockets in a single response, but I can nudge you in the right direction. the technology you are looking for is called `SignalR`. fetching data with javascript is NOT the proper way of doing this, because you want notifications to be updated real-time without pooling.